# Immutable spring request scoped beans

Tags: java, spring, scope, request

I'd like to be able to instantiate a request-scoped bean which is also immutable by using constructor parameters.
Something like the following (which of course doesn't work):

`RequestContextFactory.java`

```
package org.springframework.samples.mvc.requestscope;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.RequestScope;

@Configuration
public class RequestContextFactory {
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public RequestContext getRequestContext(TestBean bean) {
        return new RequestContext(bean);
    }
}
```

`MyController.java`

```
package org.springframework.samples.mvc.requestscope;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    RequestContextFactory requestContextFactory;

    @RequestMapping("/my")
    public @ResponseBody String simple(TestBean bean) {
        RequestContext requestContext = requestContextFactory.getRequestContext(bean);
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Spring complains that it cannot autowire a `TestBean` bean to create `RequestContext`.
How can I achieve immutability of a request-scoped bean which needs constructor parameters only known in the controller?

I'd like to be able to inject RequestContext into other beans (either request scope or other scopes). Is this an antipattern? Should something like `RequestContext` (or any other object with request lifecycle) be in the signature of all call hierarchy under the controller?

Note:
I thought of as a solution like for example having a `RequestContext` with default constructor and an `init(...)` method which can be called only once (would throw the second time). I don't like it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to manipulate request scoped beans?

Comment: Sounds more like a kind of interceptor/listener to me. Take a look at `<spring>.web.context.request.RequestContextListener`.

Comment: The answer seems obvious - don't make setter methods in your `TestBean` class. Spring is smart enough to still assembly your object.

Comment: BackSlash: I'm trying to create an immutable RequestContext which needs as input (for exmaple) the request parameters which are known only in the controller method.

M. Prokhorov: Please elaborate, maybe in an answer...

Sergey Prokoviev: it's not about the TestBean, I want RequestContext to be immutable